# In the terminal, how can I repeat a command multiple times on different files?

Tags: command-line

In the terminal, I want to use ffmpeg2theora to convert all the .MOV files in a certain directory to .ogv files. However, the following does not work:

```
ffmpeg2theora *.MOV
```

Is there a good way to repeat a command multiple times on different files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you use the default shell (bash), you can use the following:

```
for file in *.MOV; do ffmpeg2theora "$file"; done
```

Comment: This is more likely to work without the slashes: `for file in *.[Mm][Oo][Vv]; do ffmpeg2theora "$file"; done`

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right, I corrected my answer.

Comment: You could also set `nocaseglob` bash option to match lower-case, upper-case a mixed-case file extensions.

Comment: Thank you! I've never used bash before but it looks really useful. (Time for me to go learn!)

Answer (score 11):

`find . -iname '*.mov' -exec ffmpeg2theora '{}' \;`

To limit recursion depth, you can add `-maxdepth 1` before `-exec`

Comment: Just to state the difference between this answer and my answer: Using find will also look for files in subdirectories, the `for file in *.MOV` solution will only look in the current directory.